# How to deploy Flask application in google app engine with core python packages?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I want to deploy below python structure in google app engine I want to know how to configure .yaml files for below flask application with core python packages and please suggest a better way to deploy code in google app engine.(I want to deploy all the packages in one location/directory)

Packages:

```
 Model-Engine
    - api
            - api
                - __int__.py
                - view.py
                - utils.py
                - models.py
            - tests
            - runserver.py
            - setup.py
   - driver
        - driver
            - core
                - __init__.py
                - celery.py
                - celery_tasks.py
            - tests
            - setup.py


 Physics
            - core
                     - core
                        - __init__.py
                            - base.py
                            - pipe_line_simulation.py
                    -tests
            - setup.py


 Gas-model
            - src
                - model
                        - __init__.py
                        - gas_model.py
                - converter
                        - __init__.py
                        - hdf5_to_csv.py
            - setup.py
```

Comment: your project running fine with google app engine localy ?

Comment: Not now, I have created a sample flask app its working fine. But in this case, we have an existing project with one flask app and many other core packages(scientific packages) and there are lot of dependencies so I want to know that what will the best way to manage all the thing

Comment: It could be related to the packages you are using. If you use many scientific packages, you probably need to go to Flexible Environment. If your app is not designed for App Engine, I would recommend going directly to a non-compat runtime. Here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible you have some examples (check out scipy, numpy folders). If you need to install native packages (apt), check extending_runtime folder.

Answer (score 0):

## My suggestion.

1.Create application in Google admin console [google admin console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine?src=ac)

2. Put app.yaml inside your project root directory

sample code:

```
application: "Application name from google app engine"
version: 1 
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /
  script: home.app

- url: /index\.html
  script: home.app

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin
```

3. Make folder (`lib`) inside the root directory put all the dependencies inside the folder
4. Create a file `appengine_config.py` inside the project directory and put the below codes.

`from google.appengine.ext import vendor`

`vendor.add('lib')`

5. Run the app localy using this command - dev_appserver.py .
6. Deploy the application.

   `appcfg.py update -A {your-project-id} -V v1` .

If this isn't your first deployment, you will need to set the new version as the default version with

```
appcfg.py set_default_version -V v1 -A {your-project-id}
```

Congratulations! Your application is now live at your-app-id.appspot.com